# Conditional tag doesn't work in WordPress plugin

Tags: plugins, php, conditional-tags

I'm developing a plugin which can change the whole content of a special page in WordPress with an image. 
My plugin's code is here:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Test1234
 */
function set_header_page(){
    if( is_page('img') ){
    header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
    }    
}
add_action('init', 'set_header_page');

function replace_image_content(){
    if( is_page('img') ){
        $image = plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'1404-1.jpg';
        readfile($image);
    }
}
add_action('wp_loaded', 'replace_image_content');
```

My problem is here: In both functions when I add `if( is_page('img') )` nothing happens. Without `if( is_page('img') )` I see my image in all pages. This shows me in my code everything depends on 'if(is_page( 'pagename' ) )'.
How can I solve it?

Note that I tried it by `if( $post->ID == 11 )`, too.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `readfile()` does support URL addresses; however, looking at your code, you should use `plugin_dir_path()` and not `plugin_dir_url()`. Just my 1 cent. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both those hooks are too early to use `is_page()`. WordPress hasn't determined which page is being loaded yet, so it can't check the current page. Try `template_redirect` for both:

```
/**
 * Plugin Name: Test1234
 */
function replace_image_content(){
    if ( is_page( 'img' ) ) {
        header( 'Content-Type: image/jpg' );

        $image = plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . '1404-1.jpg';

        readfile( $image );

        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'replace_image_content' );
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works correctly. You are great!!!